# Cleaner way of reseting Angular form

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

For an example, let's say I have a form that is built as below.

```
buildForm() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        myString = this.formBuilder.control('default'),
        myBool = this.formBuilder.control(true),
        nonDefaultString = this.formBuilder.control(null)
    });
}
```

From here a user interacts and updates the values so something other than the defaults. When a user saves the values to the database, they are routed back to the same page and I want to restore my defaults. I don't want to call the `this.buildForm()` function because then I lose all of my listeners and is all around a clunky way of resetting. I have seen examples of using `this.myForm.reset()` but this **resets all values to null**, and I have a non null constraint for boolean values. I understand that I could do

```
this.form.reset({
    myString: 'default',
    myBool: true
});
```

But when the objects get large and I am possibly resetting them in different components, I don't want to haul around default values for each reset that require a nonnull value.

I would like to get my defaults from when I built the form. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Where are the listeners being bound? Could you re-bind them in the buildForm() method? Could you provide a bit more code to show the problems you are facing.

Comment: Maybe you can try saving all the values to a service when the form is submitted and then when the user is renavigated you can check if the values are there in the service and then populate them?

Comment: @KurtHamilton The listeners could be on the parent component for updataing to the server or on child components for when a certain values changes (instead of using ngOnChanges). The main problem I'm facing is I want to reset to my build defaults, not null defaults.

Comment: @NicholasK I've thought about that, and it's what I might have to resort to. I was just hoping there was a way baked into how forms work.

Comment: As far as I know, there is only one clean way of clearing a form and that is with `this.myForm.reset()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formGroup reset() method takes an optional argument which is the form values to reset to. So you could save the values in a variable right after initializing the form like:

`const defaultValues = myForm.value;`

Then when you want to reset back to the defaults you do:
`myForm.reset(defaultValues):`

Comment: I do like this solution. It keeps one initialization of the defaults. The only thing I would change in the answer is `myForm.getRawValue()` in case there are some disabled values.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `patchValue()` and also `setValue()`

```
this.form.patchValue({
    myString: 'default',
    myBool: true
},{emitEvent: false});
```

Emit event is false because when the values are set this will trigger other `valueChanges` events so it will become a loop so to avoid it emitEvent is set to false

Similarly u can make use of the `setValue()`

```
this.form.setValue({
    myString: 'default',
    myBool: true
},{emitEvent: false});
```

Try these might work...Good luck..!!

Comment: although these will update my object with the defaults, it is not a cleaner solution than doing `this.form.reset(defaultObject)`